# How to display author above content-single.php post

Tags: php

I am using a modified version of the Twenty Sixteen wordpress theme and I would like to have the author display at the top of the post.

Currently I have the author username being posted but this isn't what I want

Here is how I did it

```
    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
    <?php $username = get_userdata( $post->post_author ); ?>    
    <p style="display:inline-block;">Author: </p> <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( $post->post_author ); ?>"><?php echo $username->user_nicename; ?></a>
    <?php the_date('m-d-Y', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
    <br />
```

But like I said this displays 'Author : (username)' which is not what I want. I want their author name to display.

I know that I'm close. But when I try to replace the username portion nothing displays. So I must be doing that wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `the_author();` you can read more about it [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author).

Comment: Perfect. Nice and easy. I knew I was close. Thanks for helping a noob out. Will accept answer when it lets me.